# Recording sound in watchOS Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, watchkit

I am very new to developing with Xamarin so I am writing it in C# since this is what I know. I am trying to make a simple Watch application that will record audio and then return the decibel value. I know this is possible since there is a watch app that is doing something like this already but more complex in the App Store. I have found examples on how to record audio with the AVAudioRecorder on iOS but nothing on WatchOS. I haven't tried any other methods since I am so new to this and AVAudioRecorder seems to be the most used.

Here are the 2 issues I am facing:

1. I have started my audio session with avaudiosession and when I go to use AVAudioRecorder.Create() it says that Create() isn't a part of AVAudioRecorder. Is there something that needs to be imported?
2. When I go to call the AVAudioRecorder (var record = new AVAudioRecorder) and I try to debug it always crashes the app at this point. If I don't use the "new" and just call for example (_recorder.isMeteringEnabled) it throws an exception of null reference.

All this code is in the main interface controller for the watch and inside its own function.

I am basically following this example: https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/ios/media/sound/record_sound

Here is some of my code for recording:

```
    // initializing my variables for recording
    public partial class InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController
    {
    public AVAudioPlayer _player;
    public AVAudioRecorder _recorder;
    }

    //my function calling the recording
    public void Listen() {

        var audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
        audioSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.PlayAndRecord);
        audioSession.SetActive(true);

        string fileName = string.Format("myfile.caf");
        string audioFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);

        Console.WriteLine("Audio File Path: " + audioFilePath);

        NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromFilename(audioFilePath);

        Console.WriteLine("Audio File Path: " + url);

        //creating values that will be combined with keys to create the dictionary
        NSObject[] values = new NSObject[]
        {
            NSNumber.FromFloat(44100.0f),

        NSNumber.FromInt32((int)AudioToolbox.AudioFormatType.LinearPCM),
            NSNumber.FromInt32(2),
            NSNumber.FromInt32(16),
            NSNumber.FromBoolean(false),
            NSNumber.FromBoolean(false)
        };
        NSObject[] keys = new NSObject[]
        {
            AVAudioSettings.AVSampleRateKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVFormatIDKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey
        };

        //set settings with the values and keys to create the dictionary
        settings = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(values, keys);

        try {
            _recorder = new AVAudioRecorder(); //CRASHES HERE
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception", ex);
        }
        //_recorder.MeteringEnabled = true;
        //_recorder.Record();
        //_recorder.UpdateMeters();
        //var decibels = _recorder.AveragePower(0);
        //Console.WriteLine(decibels);
    }
```

Comment: You should add the actual code that you are using and Exception/stacktrace (and/or the device log error) to your question. Also have enabled the `Microphone Usage Description` in the plist? Otherwise there will be a security violation error....

Comment: I added my code in. I am not seeing any errors when it crashes. I did enable the Microphone usage in the plist for the the watchAppExtension. is this the correct spot?